# Is there any Cornetto reference in Hot Fuzz?

Tags: hot-fuzz, the-worlds-end, cornetto-trilogy, shaun-of-the-dead

The Cornetto trilogy consists of:

- *Shaun of the Dead*
- *Hot Fuzz*
- *The World’s End*

I saw that Shaun (Simon Pegg) grabs a Cornetto from the Indian store in *Shaun of the Dead.* Also Andy (Nick Frost) tries to catch an empty Cornetto cover at the end of *The World’s End* when talking about organic food. However, I cannot recall any reference to a cornetto in *Hot Fuzz.*

Is there an actual reference to it in *Hot Fuzz?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a [***featurette***](http://www.chud.com/139527/worlds-end-featurette-explains-the-cornetto-in-joke/) to [**The World's End**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1213663/) that explains the [*Cornetto trilogy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Flavours_Cornetto_trilogy).

**[Hot Fuzz](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425112/)** features the ***blue Cornetto*** ([to signify the police element](http://www.edgarwrighthere.com/2013/08/01/usa-the-worlds-end-trilogy-screenings-with-amc-august-22nd/)):

[image: Cornetto]

[image: Cornetto]

- Watch the [***featurette***](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDu1oYi3AoA) for more info

Comment: that featurette explained everything!!